# Error recibiendo data json con XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Estoy tratando de enviar los datos en XMLHttpRequest a través de json, en el registro recibo correctamente y la información de los datos es correcta, pero en el php no puedo recopilar los datos, esto funciona con una salida () y los $data en el archivo php, si sacas $data si el texto de respuesta está vacío, si sacas exit(), se transforma en algunos caracteres extraños con ? y más tonterías, y si usa $_POST, muestra array() y algunos caracteres extraños nuevamente después de la matriz vacía. La parte js se envía al hacer click en el chart.js y luego se accede desde report.php al hacer click en un icono, no se si al acceder así no me llega la info del js, ya que solo obtener una página en blanco. Este es el js y el php:

```
onComplete: function() {
                        console.log(myChart.toBase64Image());
                        var imgData = myChart.toBase64Image();
                        var imgRes = imgData.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
                        var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                                console.log(xhttp.responseText);
                                if (xhttp.status === 200) {
                                    console.log('successful');
                                 } else {
                                    console.log('failed');
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                        xhttp.open("POST", base_url_admin+"record/reporte", true);
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                        let data = JSON.stringify({"resultChartImg": imgRes});
                        xhttp.send(data);
                    }
```

php:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);exit();
```

Comment: ¿Y si haces un `print_r($_POST);` te sale algo?

Comment: @masterguru sale vacio el array

Comment: Para la prueba que sugiere @masterguru, quita la declaración del `header`, porque si haces el print_r al final no va a ser json. Yo haría una simple línea `print_r($_POST)`. ¿Es así como te sale vacío el array? Prueba también a hacerlo con `let data = JSON.stringify({test: "texto de prueba"});` en la llamada, en lugar del `let data = ...` que tienes

Comment: el print_r($_POST) me muestra esto: Array
(
)
, el array vacio y a contiuacion lo que creo que es la imagen sin el decode, con un monton de interrogaciones y demas, pero cuando pongo un exit en el php si que me devuelve el array correctamente lo que pasa es que no sigue el php por el exit

Comment: @VFG acabo de actualizarlo, alguna idea?

Comment: @VFG me parece muy raro que $data este siendo usado porque sin el no muestra lo que tiene que mostrar pero si hago un print_r de $data salga vacio